# Creating Shipping Method in spree from backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I want to create a  shipping method in spree from backend, from front end I am able to achieve it. But in backend when I run this

`Spree::ShippingMethod.create(name: "Name 1", zone_id: 1).errors.full_messages`

I am getting error

`["Calculator can't be blank"]`
It seems it needs Spree::Calculator to be created in some way. I am beginner in Spree any help will be helpful.

Comment: It would be nice if you specify the version of `spree` you are using

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to specify a `Calculator`.

Spree comes with some calculators:

- Spree::Calculator::DefaultTax
- Spree::Calculator::Shipping::FlatRate

You can also create one as explained [here](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/calculators.html#creating-a-new-calculator) and after that you can create a `ShippingMethod` this way:

`Spree::ShippingMethod.create(name: "Name 1", calculator: Spree::Calculator.first)` or whatever `Calculator` you want.

Comment: We can't directly assign calculator, while creating the shipping method, as they are protected attributes. We have to do something like this,  `zone = Spree::Zone.find_by_name("North America")
shipping_method = Spree::ShippingMethod.new(name: "Pickup from Market", zone_id: zone.id)
shipping_method.calculator_type = "Spree::Calculator::FlatRate" shipping_method.save!`

Comment: Yeah, I think we are using different versions of `spree`. I'm using `3.4.4` and your code gives me `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'zone_id' for Spree::ShippingMethod` and mine works ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way will be:-

```
zone = Spree::Zone.find_by_name("North America")
shipping_method = Spree::ShippingMethod.new(name: "Pickup from Market", zone_id: zone.id)
shipping_method.calculator_type = "Spree::Calculator::FlatRate"
shipping_method.save!
```

In place of calculator_type we can specify any type of calculator.Because I wanted the Flate Rate I used this one.

Comment: I'm getting `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'zone_id' for Spree::ShippingMethod` in spree `3.4.4`

Answer (score 0):

Spree 4.6

```
    shipping_method = Spree::ShippingMethod.new(name: "Pickup from Market")
    shipping_method.calculator_type = "Spree::Calculator::FlatRate"
    shipping_method.shipping_categories.push(Spree::ShippingCategory.first)
    shipping_method.display_on = 'both'
    shipping_method.save!
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).